# requestAnimFrame 60FPS in Chrome, 1FPS in FF

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I recently created a canvas animation with `requestAnimFrame` and was really pleased with the results in Chrome but in FF, it looked a slideshow is running. I don't know what's causing this issue.

Also, when I reduce the number of particles from 500 to <50 then the animation in FF is smooth but still not at 60FPS. Here's my code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight,
    circles = [];

canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H; 

//Random Circles creator
function create() {

    //Place the circles at the center

    this.x = W/2;
    this.y = H/2;


    //Random radius between 2 and 6
    this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3; 

    //Random velocities
    this.vx = -10 + Math.random()*20;
    this.vy = -10 + Math.random()*20;

    //Random colors
    this.r = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    circles.push(new create());
}

function draw() {

    //Fill canvas with black color
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //Fill the canvas with circles
    for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){
        var c = circles[j];

        //Create the circles
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+c.r+", "+c.g+", "+c.b+", 0.5)";
        ctx.fill();

        c.x += c.vx;
        c.y += c.vy;
        c.radius -= .05;

        if(c.radius < 0)
            circles[j] = new create();
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

animate();
```

And [here's the live demo](http://cssdeck.com/item/preview/591/particles-explosion-with-html5-canvas). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I can see some tiny optimisations: when you create a circle give them another field fillStyle so that you only have to build the rgba string once per object, and per calculate 2pi at the start, rather than on every move of every circle, but I doubt that'll make much difference.

Comment: Problem comes from the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` calls which are expensive on Firefox.

Remove them and it will work as expected in Firefox. (you don't really need them)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this works without the `globalCompositeOperation` references:

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight,
    circles = [];

canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H; 

//Random Circles creator
function create() {

    //Place the circles at the center

    this.x = W/2;
    this.y = H/2;


    //Random radius between 2 and 6
    this.radius = 2 + Math.random()*3; 

    //Random velocities
    this.vx = -10 + Math.random()*20;
    this.vy = -10 + Math.random()*20;

    //Random colors
    this.r = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random())*255;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    circles.push(new create());
}

function draw() {

    //Fill canvas with black color
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //Fill the canvas with circles
    for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){
        var c = circles[j];

        //Create the circles
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+c.r+", "+c.g+", "+c.b+", 0.5)";
        ctx.fill();

        c.x += c.vx;
        c.y += c.vy;
        c.radius -= .05;

        if(c.radius < 0)
            circles[j] = new create();
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```